# How to convert a View Id to int

Tags: android, integer, int

```
       public void buttonA1(View view) { 
        int[] board = {R.id.A1, R.id.A2, R.id.A3, R.id.B1, R.id.B2, R.id.B3,   R.id.C1, R.id.C2, R.id.C3}; 
        int i=view.getId().intValue; //even this one didn't work
       }
```

I would like to convert a view Id to `int` so that i can look it up in the array as shown. How do I do that?
I tried something like this `int posNew = Arrays.asList(board).indexOf(view.getId())` but it kept saying the array has no object of type `Integer`.
I even tried this `int posNew =Arrays.asList(board).indexOf(view.getId())`, but still it didn't work.

Comment: What's your intention with these ids ?

Comment: Id of a view is already an integer. You have nothing to convert. Do `int i=view.getId()` directly.

Answer (score 2):

`int i=view.getId();` will return the view id as integer value.
And use sorting logic to check the position of the id in array of integer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to add them to an array, but this will work

```
ArrayList<Integer>arrayList;
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

arrayList.add(new Integer(R.id.button));
arrayList.add(new Integer(R.id.button1));
.
.
.
```

> ArrayList need objects so wrap the primitive int in an Integer object like
>   so

```
new Integer(R.id.button)
```

Comment: But if I search for that Id in the array like this int posNew = Arrays.asList(board).indexOf(view.getId()); then it flags it saying the list may not contain objects of type Integer which means the view.getId() is returning an Integer not int.

Comment: to retrieve an array object use :

int posNew = arrayList.indexOf(new Integer(view.getId()));

Answer (score 0):

View's Id **IS** integer already. No need to convert anything. If you want to convert `int` to `Integer` then:

```
Integer viewId = new Integer(view.getId());
```

would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()), the `getId()` method already returns an int. No conversion or methods are needed